# Find which RAR file is bad

Tags: archive, rar

I have a RAR I downloaded made up of multiple files. When trying to extract it, it tells me the data is incomplete, something bad with one of the files.
Considering I had to download multiple large files, is there a way to find out exactly which of the files I should re-download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [MacPar deluxe](http://gp.home.xs4all.nl/Site/MacPAR_deLuxe.html) it checks each part - and if the parts include .par files it can recover from some errors

Comment: "A checksum error (2) occurred during Unrar, or an invalid password was entered" hmm... (there was no password - and not sure how the checksum thing helps). But good software otherwise.

Comment: If a rar is split up then it should use .par files to help spot where the error is

Answer (score 1):

[UnRarX](http://www.unrarx.com/) also has an option to test archives without extracting them.